# Как заставить андроид не валить приложение при долгих вычислениях?

Tags: android, java, android-asynctask, многопоточность

Всем добрый день и с ДНЕМ ПОБЕДЫ!
Родился следующий вопрос: возможно ли в программе организовать `onCreate()` так, чтобы он не рушился при долгом выполнении процесса. Конечно я пытался все сложные вычисления проводить через `Thread` но у меня ничего хорошего все равно не выходит! На эмуляторе все запускается - работает! На девайсе все активити работают нормально кроме того где производятся вычисления. Вот я думаю как можно это обойти? Буду рад любой помощи! Если нужно, могу выложить исходник последнего активити, но там целая простыня!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В документации ясно сказано, что метод **onCreate()** создан для инициализации активности. То есть указание на ресурс с UI (**setContentView()**) либо создание своего, а также получение доступа к необходимым элементам пользовательского интерфейса (**findViewById()**).  И чтобы обезопасить пользователя от томительного ожидания, ограничили время 3-мя секундами.
Если есть необходимость что-либо просчитать и от этого зависит то, как будет выглядеть экран для пользователя, можно запустить в **onCreate()** задачу [**AsyncTask**](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), пусть все считается в ней, а пользователю отобразить круглый **ProgressBar**.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // setContentView(...);
   // findViewById(...);

   task= new MyTask();
   task.execute();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
   super.onDestroy();
   if (task != null) {
       task.cancel(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: А можно подробнее про AsyncTasc. Как мне его лучше инициализировать всунуть туда расчеты от которых в конечном итоге будет зависеть отображаемая информация!

Comment: Вот отправные точки:  
[Документация по AsyncTask] [1]  
[Статья про AsyncTask на русском] [2]  
А дальше ищите в интернете, информации по ним очень много.  

  [1]:http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
  [2]:http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/149-urok-86-asynctask-znakomstvo-neslozhnyj-primer.html